# Filtering and Sorting results with WebSockets?

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm fairly new to both node.js & socket.io but I've built a websocket end point that pushes simple data to a front end.

**Example:**
`{
 name  : "Bob",
 eyes  : "green",
 score : 100,
 fav   : "true"
}`

Easy enough using node.js/socket.io (*so easy!!*) but my question is:

Is there a way to filter and/or sort the data prior to being pushed to the client side? I realize that I could do this with JS in the browser, but if I have 600 people being pushed and the end user only wants people with "green" eyes it seems like a waste to push the 550 users that don't have green eyes to the browser just to then strip them out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After quite a bit of research and playing, I've concluded that the best method to accomplish this would be to setup socket "channels" for each filter point. Using my initial post as an example, I'd have a channel for green, blue, brown (etc) eyes and then subscribe users to that channel based on their requirements. Filtering would then be done on the client side to ensure no duplicates show in the list/grid.

Comment: I know this is quite old now, so just wondering if you still consider this to be the best method?

Comment: IMO, it is. This question was based on a project I was working on at the time and it's since been a huge success in our company as a source of real-time data. The channels work well and end users like that they can control the scope of data by subscribing and unsubscribing from channels.